# Suppose $F_s$ is a PRF. Is $F'_s(x)=F_x(s)$ also a PRF?

Tags: pseudo-random-generator, pseudo-random-function

Suppose $F_s$ be a family of keyed pseudorandom functions. Define $F'_s(x)=F_x(s)$. Is $F'_s$ a family of pseudorandom functions? It seems false but I am able to give a proof assuming $F$ is constructed from a length doubling PRG. It is essentially the same proof as construction of PRF from PRG. I don't know if this proof is correct. Can someone tell me if the statement is true or false?

Comment: Note that the statement you are trying to prove or disprove is an implication. I.e., you are trying to prove/disprove the statement "If $F$ is a family of PRFs, then $F'$ is also a family of PRFs." Having a **single** positive example, i.e., a single instance of $F$ where $F'$ is also a PRF, tells you nothing about the validity of the statement. On the other hand, having a single **counterexample**, i.e., a single PRF-family $F$ such that $F'$ is **not** a family of PRFs, **disproves** the statement.

Comment: So in general is the statement false?

Comment: Can you come up with a counter example?

Comment: Is this a homework? Could you indicate of the origin of this question?

Comment: it is not a homework question. i conjectured this to help solve some other problem.

Answer (score 2):

No. If $F$ is a PRF family with a *weak key*, i.e., a key that forces it to behave insecurely, then $F'$ is not a PRF.

Weak-key PRF: Let $G$ be a secure PRF. We construct another secure PRF, $F$ with a weak key $\hat k$. Define $F_k(x) = G_k(x)$ for all $k \neq \hat k$. Then define $F_{\hat k}(x) = x$ for all $x$. $F$ is still a PRF, because the likelihood of selecting $\hat k$ from the space of keys is negligible.

However, $F'$ is not a secure PRF with this definition of $F$. An adversary may simply query for $\hat k$ and recieve the full key $F'_x(\hat k) = F_{\hat k}(x) = x$.

Comment: By the way, this might be a HW

Answer (score 0):

$F'$ need not be a secure PRF. Consider: $F$ be a (keyed) Pseudo-Random Permutation defined over: $\mathcal{X} \times \mathcal{X} \to \mathcal{X}$. By the [PRF-PRP switching lemma](https://crypto.stanford.edu/%7Edabo/courses/cs255_winter07/PRP-PRF.pdf), then $F_s$ is a secure PRF (up to a certain number of queries). Note that $F'_s$ is well defined since the key and message output spaces are the same.

**Claim**: A two-queries adversary distinguishes $F'$ from a truly random function with overwhelming probability.

As an aside, PRFs that are secure when keyed by the input are called swap PRFs. When the PRF is secure, when keyed either way, then the PRF is a dual-PRF. Some PRFs have this nice property; an example is HMAC. [Backendal et al. show that HMAC is a dual PRF](https://eprint.iacr.org/2023/861) when the inputs satisfy certain properties, as is usually the case in protocols that rely on the dual PRF security of HMAC.

Comment: By the way, this might be a HW

Comment: @kelalaka, that was my guess as well. Hence, I kept the explanation a bit incomplete.

Comment: I've asked the OP for clarification..

Comment: thanks for the answer this is very interesting.

Comment: @Suraj, if you've got the details, feel free to post an answer expanding on that.